# Setting a unique Key on a Grommet DataTable Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, grommet

I encountered an error earlier: 
`Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,`project`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.`

This error was coming from a Grommet DataTable I have been using. The issue is on my table, the first column is "type", which can have one of two options: project, or task. Grommet automatically takes the first column as the key, which is not what I want since the keys will become duplicates.

I have thoroughly gone through Grommets documentation and have attempted to input the primary key like they have instructed here:

https://v2.grommet.io/datatable#primaryKey

My first attempt was using the primaryKey as they instructed, see first attempt in code below.

My second attempt is I inputted the data._id as a column, and set primary to true. This works, but I don't want the data._id to display in my table, I just want to set it as the key.

```
`<DataTable
    sortable={true}
//this is what I attempted but nothing happened
    primaryKey={data._id}
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
/>`
```

I want to set the key to data._id, because it is a unique identifier, however, I do not want data._id to display in my table.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems that the lib lacks support for your case :). My suggestion is to go with your attempt 2 and use css to hide that column

Answer (score 1):

primaryKey needs to be a string, so in this case, it would be:

```
`<DataTable
    sortable={true}
    primaryKey="_id"
    columns={}
  />`
```